# how can I fetch user and user groups from FreeIPA systems with Ansible

Tags: ansible, freeipa

I recently automated the tasks where I added users and groups by using `freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipauser` and `freeipa.ansible_freeipa.ipagroup` modules. I was told to fetch and gather users and group facts from IPA systems and deploy them at any time in the new system.

I decided to look for a module something like `ipa_user_facts` and turns out that there is no such module. I have been using roles from `https://github.com/freeipa/ansible-freeipa`, however, I cannot find the facts module for freeipa in any other sources.

Can anyone tell me how could I proceed with this task?

Comment: Can you share your ansible playbook code with us so that we can figure out the issue

Comment: "_How could I proceed with this task?_", maybe by [How to export all FreeIPA users list to a CSV format?](https://serverfault.com/questions/919728/) and follow up with [groups](https://listman.redhat.com/archives/freeipa-users/2014-January/msg00246.html), [How do I list all IPA groups on Linux](https://serverfault.com/a/980779/448950), etc. ...

Comment: After reading your description "_fetch and gather users and group facts from IPA systems and deploy them at any time in the new system_" it seems to be a kind of backup and restore task. For this there is a role [`ipabackup`](https://github.com/freeipa/ansible-freeipa/blob/master/roles/ipabackup/README.md) into which you could have a look.